# How to get PATH_SEPARATOR to work when choosing a file path for uploading an image

Tags: php

I am using php code to upload an image, in my images.php file I have a directory which looks like the first line in the block of code below. I realise this won't work for a mac (I am working off a windows). This is obviously a problem as if I am working off a mac I will have to change this line of code each time I swap between computers. Is there anyway to automatically update it. I researched PATH_SEPARATOR but I have no idea how to incorporate into my code.

```
$target_dir = "..\\img\\uploads\\";
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["fileToUpload"]
["name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$target_file = $target_dir . uniqid() . '.' . $imageFileType ;
$user_id = $_SESSION['userId'];
```

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep You can use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` which is a PHP predefined constant which is going to provide the right directory separator either a backslash or a forward slash based on the operating system .
You can do something like this:

```
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$target_dir = ".." . $ds . "img" . $ds . "uploads" . $ds;
```

for more information check out [PHP predefined constants](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php)

Comment: Using this code doesn't work. It no longer saves the details about the image into the database. I also have ajax on the page and it that isn't working anymore

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: showRequest is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (jquery.js:608) and in the network it is no longer showing the image.php when I click the upload button